# Nested line break in H3 tag

Tags: html, wordpress

I"ve one heading we can call we are display it inside H3 tag.

So we need to add line break so it will be like bellow example. can please help to get it resolve:

```
<h3>This (Line Break) is (Line Break) heading</h3>
```

Note:

```
<br/> , /n
```

is not working

Comment: Don't use <br> it's not legacy, but it's considered a bad practice, with CSS you have more controll. 3 separate <h3> would do, just change margin, you can also controll line-height. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br#Styling_with_CSS

Comment: One more solution would be simply making parent element smaller, so text in h3 will break.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br>` inside the `<h3>` tag

```html
<h3>
test <br>
test <br>
test
</h3>
```

Comment: Use the SO build in Fiddle instead of the external one.